# How do I breakout from a loop and stop a counter variable in Jascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
const array = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
function choice() {
let arrayChoice = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
return arrayChoice;
}
choice()

const result = textContent = document.querySelector('#result')
const rock = document.querySelector('#rock')
const paper = document.querySelector('#scissors')
const scissors = document.querySelector('#paper')
const playerGame = document.querySelector('.player--game')
const computerGame = document.querySelector('.computer--game')
const playerScore = document.querySelector('.player-score')
const computerScore = document.querySelector('.computer-score')

let playerPoint = 0;
let computerPoint = 0;

function playRound(player, computer) {
  rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let player = 'rock';
  computer = choice();
  if(computer == 'paper' && player == 'rock') {
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'paper beats rock'
  }else if(computer == 'scissors' && player == 'rock') {
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'rock beats scissors'
  }else if(computer == 'rock' && player == 'rock') {
    result.textContent = 'I\'ts a tie';
  }
  
  playerGame.innerHTML +='<br>' + '<br> '+ player;
  computerGame.innerHTML +='<br>' + '<br> '+ computer;
  })

paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
  player = 'paper'
  computer = choice();
  if(computer == 'scissors' && player == 'paper') {
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'scissors beats paper';
  }else if(computer == 'rock' && player == 'paper'){
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'paper beats rock';
  }else if(computer == 'paper' && player == 'paper') {
    result.textContent = 'I\'ts a tie';
  }

  playerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ player;
  computerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ computer;
})


scissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let player = 'scissors';
  computer = choice();
  if(computer == 'paper' && player == 'scissors') {
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'scissors beats paper';
  }else if(computer == 'rock' && player == 'scissors') {
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'rock beats scissors';
  }else if(computer == 'scissors' && player == 'scissors') {
    result.textContent = 'I\'ts a tie';
  }
  
  playerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ player;
  computerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ computer;
})
}
playRound()




const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if(playerPoint >= 5 && computerPoint < 5) {
        result.textContent = "Player Won";
      }else if(playerPoint < 5 && computerPoint >= 5) {
        result.textContent = "Computer Won";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
button {
  padding: 1em;
}

#result {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex; 
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}

.score-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Rock,Paper,Scissors</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="object container">
    <button id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="scissors">paper</button>
    <button id="paper">scissors</button>
  </div>

    <!--result-->
    <div id="result">--</div>

    <!--counter board-->
    <div class="score-board">
      <p class="player-score">0</p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p class="computer-score">0</p>
    </div>

    <!--player game played-->
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p>player</p>
      <p class="player--game"></p>
    </div>

    <!--computer game played-->
    <div>
      <p>computer</p>
      <p class="computer--game"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a building a ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS project that counts the score between a player and computer and whoever gets to 5 points the game has to stop and display the winner of the 5 round, and I have been stuck trying to write a `for-loop` that `breaks` the counter when a player hits 5 points, but nothing seems to be working the counter, keeps counter even when the condition is met when a player hits 5 point. Here is my code below

```js
const array = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
function choice() {
let arrayChoice = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
return arrayChoice;
}
choice()

const result = textContent = document.querySelector('#result')
const rock = document.querySelector('#rock')
const paper = document.querySelector('#scissors')
const scissors = document.querySelector('#paper')
const playerGame = document.querySelector('.player--game')
const computerGame = document.querySelector('.computer--game')
const playerScore = document.querySelector('.player-score')
const computerScore = document.querySelector('.computer-score')

let playerPoint = 0;
let computerPoint = 0;

function playRound(player, computer) {
  rock.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let player = 'rock';
  computer = choice();
  if(computer == 'paper' && player == 'rock') {
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'paper beats rock'
  }else if(computer == 'scissors' && player == 'rock') {
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'rock beats scissors'
  }else if(computer == 'rock' && player == 'rock') {
    result.textContent = 'I\'ts a tie';
  }
  
  playerGame.innerHTML +='<br>' + '<br> '+ player;
  computerGame.innerHTML +='<br>' + '<br> '+ computer;
  })

paper.addEventListener('click', () => {
  player = 'paper'
  computer = choice();
  if(computer == 'scissors' && player == 'paper') {
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'scissors beats paper';
  }else if(computer == 'rock' && player == 'paper'){
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'paper beats rock';
  }else if(computer == 'paper' && player == 'paper') {
    result.textContent = 'I\'ts a tie';
  }

  playerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ player;
  computerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ computer;
})


scissors.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let player = 'scissors';
  computer = choice();
  if(computer == 'paper' && player == 'scissors') {
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'scissors beats paper';
  }else if(computer == 'rock' && player == 'scissors') {
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    result.textContent = 'rock beats scissors';
  }else if(computer == 'scissors' && player == 'scissors') {
    result.textContent = 'I\'ts a tie';
  }
  
  playerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ player;
  computerGame.innerHTML += '<br>' + '<br>'+ computer;
})
}
playRound()




const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playRound()
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if(playerPoint >= 5 && computerPoint < 5) {
        result.textContent = "Player Won";
      }else if(playerPoint < 5 && computerPoint >= 5) {
        result.textContent = "Computer Won";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
button {
  padding: 1em;
}

#result {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex; 
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}

.score-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Rock,Paper,Scissors</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="object container">
    <button id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="scissors">paper</button>
    <button id="paper">scissors</button>
  </div>

    <!--result-->
    <div id="result">--</div>

    <!--counter board-->
    <div class="score-board">
      <p class="player-score">0</p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p class="computer-score">0</p>
    </div>

    <!--player game played-->
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p>player</p>
      <p class="player--game"></p>
    </div>

    <!--computer game played-->
    <div>
      <p>computer</p>
      <p class="computer--game"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Observation #1:  Your game is not a loop.  It plays out as a series of events like button clicks and handlers for those events.  Observation #2:  The loop you have written in the button click handlers is redundant (just checks the same state over and over 5 times).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. How do I make the button stop clicking and the counter stop counting when either the player reaches 5 points?

Comment: I'm not sure if ```buttons.forEach``` is required to check a player that reaches 5 point first, i just gave it a try, it works the same in the separated button clicks, but its too much ```code``` and since the player has to click a button to play the game. What I need the game to do now is to check a player that gets to 5 points first and display the winner of the 5 round and then stop the counter variable from counting endlessly or stop the button click, which will also stop the counter as well

Comment: I think I did my best by coming up with this approach, but I have spent enormous time just to make it work. ```Stop counter when either player reaches 5 point``` ```Display winner and end game```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "end game"?  Do you want the _Rock, Paper, Scissors_ buttons to be removed or become disabled or something like that?  There is an event listener attached to the buttons and will still be attached to the buttons even if the game ends (unless you do something about that).  You have loads of options for how to approach this.  How do you want it to work?

Comment: No, the ```Rock, Paper, Scissors``` played by ```player``` and  ```computer``` should be there, but ```stop``` not ```disappear```, once either player has met the condition which is ```5 points``` and then display the result immediately ```@ result.textContent```. I want the counter to stop counting and the displayed ```Rock, Paper, Scissors``` of both players to stop incrementing on button click probably disable the button so that a user will have no option than to refresh or reset the game I already have a ```reset button``` left aside

Comment: It would be helpful if you turned your question into a runnable snippet using the stack snippet editor.  This would allow you to provide some working HTML too. Then we could see what you mean by "want the counter to stop counting", which is a slightly strange way to ask for what you want.  Just don't click the buttons (or disable them) if you want the counter to stop.  It's like...if I want my toaster to stop making toast then I stop putting bread in it (or unplug it).

Comment: Done that now, you can see the running code

Comment: I'm really glad you added a working example.  Going forward, all questions you ask on Stack Overflow should include such a minimal reproducible example, as you have now provided.  Good job.  Upvote earned!

Comment: Do you have any improvement you can add regarding my previous query?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of changes I made to your code.

1. I renamed `array` to `options` and filled it with objects instead, ex. `{selected: 'rock', beatenBy: 'paper'}`
2. I added a data*-attribute to each button. The values are "0" for `#rocks`, "1" for `#paper` and "2" for `#scissors`.
3. The event listeners on the buttons are now just extracting the `data-value` (0, 1, 2) from the buttons.
4. I removed the event listeners in `playRound()`.
5. I removed redundant code in `playRound()`;
6. I changed the computer's random choice to just return a number.
7. I use the numbers to do a lookup in `options`.
8. I also showed two new ways of declaring strings.
9. I added `checkWinningCondition()`. You don't need to send in the global variables `playerPoint`, `computerPoint`, and `WINNING_SCORE` as parameters but it's easier to understand the call to the method if you do that.
10. I added an alert if someone won. It's up to you how it should be handled.

```js
const options = [  // 1
  {selected: 'rock', beatenBy: 'paper'},
  {selected: 'paper', beatenBy: 'scissors'},
  {selected: 'scissors', beatenBy: 'rock'}
];

const result = textContent = document.querySelector('#result')
const playerScore = document.querySelector('.player-score')
const computerScore = document.querySelector('.computer-score')

function choice() {  // 6
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
}

let playerPoint = 0;
let computerPoint = 0;
const WINNING_SCORE = 5;

function playRound(player) {
  let computer = choice();
  let playerOption = options[player];     // 7
  let computerOption = options[computer]; // 7
  let textContent = "It's a tie";         // 8

  // 4 & 5
  if (playerOption.beatenBy == computerOption.selected) {  // 1
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    textContent = `${computerOption.selected} beats ${playerOption.selected}`; // 8
  } else if (computerOption.beatenBy == playerOption.selected) {  // 1
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    textContent = `${playerOption.selected} beats ${computerOption.selected}`; // 8
  }
  
  //console.log({playerOption}, {computerOption});
  result.textContent = textContent;
  
  if (checkWinningCondition(playerPoint, computerPoint, WINNING_SCORE)) {
    alert("someone won"); // 10
  }
}

function checkWinningCondition(playerPoint, computerPoint, WINNING_SCORE) {  // 9
  return playerPoint >= WINNING_SCORE || computerPoint >= WINNING_SCORE;
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let button = event.target;
    let noWinner = !checkWinningCondition(playerPoint, computerPoint, WINNING_SCORE);   // 9, do note the ! which turns "false" to "true" and vice versa
    
    if (noWinner) { // 9
      playRound(button.dataset.value); // 3
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
button {
  padding: 1em;
}

#result {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex; 
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}

.score-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <div id="object container">
    <button id="rock" data-value="0">Rock</button>
    <button id="scissors" data-value="1">paper</button>
    <button id="paper" data-value="2">scissors</button>
  </div>

    <!--result-->
    <div id="result">--</div>

    <!--counter board-->
    <div class="score-board">
      <p class="player-score">0</p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p class="computer-score">0</p>
    </div>

    <!--player game played-->
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p>player</p>
      <p class="player--game"></p>
    </div>

    <!--computer game played-->
    <div>
      <p>computer</p>
      <p class="computer--game"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It feels good when I run the improvement you made in the code and the game ends at 5 round, and either player gets to 5 point, Its exactly what I wanted, but how can we make it to alert the correct player that won the game, for example if player reaches 5 point it should alert ```player won``` and vice versa

Comment: All the relevant variables are there for you to solve that question, as I stated in point 10. Hint: see `checkWinningCondition()`. I placed the alert there for you to replace it with a new method that handles what happens when someone wins.

Comment: Hey bro, I think I figured it out, here is what I came up with.

Comment: Thanks for supporting me to finally complete this project, and for making me find a way to make it work the way I want it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const options = [  // 1
  {selected: 'rock', beatenBy: 'paper'},
  {selected: 'paper', beatenBy: 'scissors'},
  {selected: 'scissors', beatenBy: 'rock'}
];

const result = textContent = document.querySelector('#result')
const playerScore = document.querySelector('.player-score')
const computerScore = document.querySelector('.computer-score')

function choice() {  // 6
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
}

let playerPoint = 0;
let computerPoint = 0;
const WINNING_SCORE = 5;

function playRound(player) {
  let computer = choice();
  let playerOption = options[player];     // 7
  let computerOption = options[computer]; // 7
  let textContent = "It's a tie";         // 8

  // 4 & 5
  if (playerOption.beatenBy == computerOption.selected) {  // 1
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore.textContent = computerPoint;
    textContent = `${computerOption.selected} beats ${playerOption.selected}`; // 8
  } else if (computerOption.beatenBy == playerOption.selected) {  // 1
    playerPoint++;
    playerScore.textContent = playerPoint;
    textContent = `${playerOption.selected} beats ${computerOption.selected}`; // 8
  }
  
  //console.log({playerOption}, {computerOption});
  result.textContent = textContent;
  
if (checkWinningCondition(playerPoint, computerPoint, WINNING_SCORE)) {

  // What I came up with
  if(playerPoint < WINNING_SCORE) {
    alert('computer won')
  }else if(computerPoint < WINNING_SCORE) {
    alert('player won')
  }
}
//End
}

function checkWinningCondition(playerPoint, computerPoint, WINNING_SCORE) {  // 9
  return playerPoint >= WINNING_SCORE || computerPoint >= WINNING_SCORE;
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let button = event.target;
    let noWinner = !checkWinningCondition(playerPoint, computerPoint, WINNING_SCORE);   // 9, do note the ! which turns "false" to "true" and vice versa
    
    if (noWinner) { // 9
      playRound(button.dataset.value); // 3
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
button {
  padding: 1em;
}

#result {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex; 
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}

.score-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>



<body>
  <div>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <div id="object container">
    <button id="rock" data-value="0">Rock</button>
    <button id="scissors" data-value="1">paper</button>
    <button id="paper" data-value="2">scissors</button>
  </div>

    <!--result-->
    <div id="result">--</div>

    <!--counter board-->
    <div class="score-board">
      <p class="player-score">0</p>
      <p>:</p>
      <p class="computer-score">0</p>
    </div>

    <!--player game played-->
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p>player</p>
      <p class="player--game"></p>
    </div>

    <!--computer game played-->
    <div>
      <p>computer</p>
      <p class="computer--game"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).